# Indexed file name search like Everything for Android wanted

Tags: android, file-management, search-engine, document-indexing, file-search

I want to get a file from my Android smartphone without knowing where it was saved. I know the filename. On Windows I would use [Everything](http://voidtools.com/) and would have the file immediately since the hard drive is indexed.

Can I add my smartphone to Everything once it is connected with USB in order to have it indexed? Or is there another indexing service I do not know of?

A little research showed that there is [Search Everything](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.marlon.searcheverything) for Android, seems to be the way to go for me, or is there another maybe better app? A quick research on [AlternativeTo.net](https://alternativeto.net/) shows me [AndroSearch](https://alternativeto.net/software/androsearch/) and [File Finder](https://alternativeto.net/software/file-finder-ad/). Which of the 3 is the best?

Comment: Not using any of those myself, so I cannot say which to recommend – but while waiting for answers, be welcome to check my [list of search apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_search#group_886). It's also hard to say what is "better" without knowing precisely what features you're after ;)

Comment: I used Search Everything now and found the path of the wanted documents, so the issue is solved. For your information, it displays ads in the app.

Comment: Cool, thanks for your feedback! May I suggest you [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) then and accept your answer? And yes, my list says it contains AdMob  (click the name, or see the monitor icon next to its entry):)

Comment: The app ["SearchEverything-local file fi"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=search.fastsearch.everything.searcheverything) or ["SearchEverything-local file finder&file searcher"](https://uapk.pro/searcheverything-local-file-finderfile-searcher-v-1-2-8-apk-adfree/) by the developer/distributor "Fun Max" seems to have nice search, but it re-runs the slow indexing after a few minutes, which defeats the purpose of fast search.

Comment: AndroSearch doesn't find files on the SD card.

Comment: "Jet File Search" freezes or restarts the indexing process when I switch between apps.

Answer (score 0):

[Search Everything](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.marlon.searcheverything) was the solution for me. It finds the file by filename and gives you the path so next time you know where to search. Downside is the ad that is displayed but for one time I can live with that.

Comment: Thanks for self-answering! Could you also include some words on "why" – i.e. how it fits your requirements? Oneliners with just a link are mostly frowned upon, on all SE sites. Also include the draw-back(s) you found. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This app ignores files on my SD card and lists files in internal storage as `/sdcard/`

Answer (score 0):

[Files by Google](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.nbu.files&hl=de) seems to have fast indexed file search, but only for the beginnings of words. So searching for `import` will find `my important file.mp3`, but not `myimportantfile.mp3`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether due to indexing, but in [File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alphainventor.filemanager) (called "File Manager +" after installation) by the developer "File Manager Plus", the list of results grows with results from lots of directories extremely early during the first search. Its UI is also super fast. It has some quirks though:

- For a new search to show results, in some cases you have to **kill the app** and start it again.
- Even though all search results appear quite quickly, the thingy that looks like a progress bar and behaves like a spinner keeps spinning for a long time in large directories. If you waited a few seconds, then the list of results is probably complete and there's no need to wait for the spinner to stop.

  - On the other hand, during normal navigation through directories (not search), there's no spinner that indicates that the file list is being computed. So it first looks like there are no files in the directory, and then the file list appears.

Its builtin audio player starts playback for some long audio files with a large delay. Other audio players can be used, enabling that is a bit tricky: ☰ -> Home -> ⁝ -> Settings -> disable Music Player.